# How to dynamically load components in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

Currently I'm doing it with IF, but for example in Vue.JS there is [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). Is in Angular something similar?

```
<app-tabs-choice *ngIf="action.type == 'choice'"></app-tabs-choice>
<app-tabs-comment *ngIf="action.type == 'comment'"></app-tabs-comment>
<app-tabs-message *ngIf="action.type == 'message'"></app-tabs-message>
```

Comment: You could achieve this with routes, the components are loaded only when the route is activated. Would that work for you?

Comment: this components are inside one page...

Comment: Doesn't matter, the user won't be able to tell, if that's what your worried about. You could have 1 parent route "tabs" and 3 children routes "choice", "comments", "message" and the children will be loaded only when the route is activated. And visually this will all be on the same "page".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it :-

1. using [ngSwitchCase](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase)
2. you can also achieve this with routes
3. If you have a single tab component then you can use [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) to create reusable components.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular there is [Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) but it based on routing. In other words, you can't lazyload components based on ngIf directive, but you can lazyload them if their route is different

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngComponentOutlet`, but it all depends on your use-case:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tabs[action.type] as comp" [ngComponentOutlet]="comp"></ng-container>
```

with in your component:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  readonly tabs = {
    choice: TabsChoiceComponent,
    comment: TabsCommentComponent,
    message: TabsMessageComponent
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that i need something like this. The only thing is that i get `No component factory found for ChoiceComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents` Before, with `IF` it works fine...

Comment: @Kin sure, if you use a dynamic approach, you'll need to add it to the `.entryComponents` of your `NgModule` where you declare them

Answer (score 0):

You Can Load Components Dynamically By Using Thier Name:

```
export class AdBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ads: AdItem[];
  currentAdIndex = -1;
  @ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost: AdDirective;
  interval: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
    this.getAds();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  loadComponent() {
    this.currentAdIndex = (this.currentAdIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
    const adItem = this.ads[this.currentAdIndex];

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);

    const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
  }

  getAds() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.loadComponent();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="ad-banner-example">
  <h3>Advertisements</h3>
  <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
</div>
```

For More Information Check [this link](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)